# How do I close the firefox downloads window on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

Currently, I'm using Firefox 42.0 on OS X 10.11.1. The problem I'm having is that once I open the downloads window in Firefox, the top status bar disappears and there is no way to close or resize the downloads window (there are no close, or maximize buttons).

I've tried pressing Command+J again but it doesn't close the window.

How can I close just the downloads window without having to force quit Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close the windows with no close button, you need to press `Cmd+W`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/479917)

Comment: @nKn I *am* the author of the original question. This method does infact work to close down the full-screen downloads and bookmarks windows and does not require restarting Firefox in safe mode. Let me know if I can rephrase it better.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is known bug in FireFox 42 for El Capitan.

[image]

2. The only way to fix this is to restart FireFox in Safe Mode
   [image]

A Support issue has already been created for this [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1089478).

More information on the limitations of FireFox in Safe Mode are documented [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode).